# What is the best way of converting string to a list of string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know what is the best way of converting the string into list of string

For Example:

```
__string = 'ABCDEFGHIJ'
list_string = ['AB', 'CD', 'EF', 'GH', 'IJ']
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
[a+b for a, b in (zip(*([iter(text)]*2)))]

# or

[text[i*2:i*2+2] for i in range(len(text)//2)]

# or
import re
re.findall("..?", text) //handles string of odd length
```

if the string is not even the less char will be missed. can be easily fixed if needed

Comment: I love the range of syntax here

Answer (score 0):

easy peasy xD

```
txt= 'ABCDEFGHIJ'

result = [txt[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(txt),2)]
```